# How to find a printer on another subnet

Tags: networking, printing, dhcp

I have a server with 4 ethernet ports: 1 used to connect to internet and 3 others used to manage 3 local subnets.

I configured the DHCP server, the routing, packet forwarding for IPv4 and NAT; everything seems to work correctly: all users can connect to the Internet from each subnet and users can ping a PC from one subnet to the other.

Here-below the content of my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth2 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth3 -s 192.168.3.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

What is not working is that I can't access from subnet x to a network printer/projector on subnet y *using auto-detect with the standard HP driver* but I can ping it and access the printer's management page.

*What am I missing?*

Comment: I have added info from my /etc/rc.local please let me know if you need further details

Comment: Yes I can access the web based management page from the other subnet

Comment: I try to reach the network printer using standard HP application but I'm not able to find it over network

Comment: I've edited your question to have all comments into your question. Please delete all of your comments as this is starting to look like a chat room!  **;-)** One last question: if you type the IP address instead of using the auto-detect, does it work then? (It should!)

Answer (score 0):

If you know network address of your printer and there is no network problems accessing it, you can add a printer using **CUPS web interface**:

```
http://localhost:631
```

or:

```
http://your_server:631
```

[image: Adding a printer in CUPS]